# How to restrict the selection bubbling of a listview item to it's child listview?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I've a listview which inturn has a child listview for each parent listview item. When I select an item in the parent listview, it's child listview items are also getting selection.

Is there a way to prevent this bubbling?

The following is a snippet of a parent listview item which is a user control:

"**NestedControl.xaml**" which repeats itself recursively.

```
   <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#F0F0F0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"
                                       >
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=OneWay}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.5" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <Image x:Name="Dot1" Source="{Image Path here}" 
                                           Height="6" Width="6"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,8,0,10" 
                                           RelativePanel.RightOf="Name"/>
    </RelativePanel>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding NestedEntities,Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="NestedListView" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection/>
        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="entity:Detail">
                <controls:NestedControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

[image: Nested list view]

In the image above, when i select "Main item 5", nested list view is loaded and parent list view item is getting extended.

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a nested `ListView`, but I can't reproduce the problem you said. When I clicked on the parent, the child was not selected. Can you provide a minimal runnable demo to help me better locate the problem?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I meant the selection. child items aren't getting selected in my case, but the parent listview item's selection range is covering up the child listview as well.. Applying any styling properties like pointeroverbackground, selected background to the parent listview item is cascaded to the child listview as well since it is within the parent listview item

Comment: Something like in the image above..

Comment: So you want to remove the background color of the selected item, this is a question about the style, is it?

Comment: Yes I want the selection (ie:- selection background) to be removed for the child listview when the parent listview item selection is in place. When I select "Main Item 5", the selection background should be restricted to that content alone and similarly for child list view items like "Sub Item 3"

Comment: I am sorry, but you are writing a nested ListView. The `MainItem` and the `SubItem` it owns together form a `ListViewItem`, and the background is for the entire `ListViewItemContainer`. I suggest you try `TreeView`, this control can meet your needs. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view)